# Ctrl-K Kill Line, Not Screen Edge in Visual Line Mode

Tags: org-mode

(I apologize in advance for my general technical / emacs inexperience. I use `org-mode` for writing novels, so have not delved very deep into its many options)

I have `visual-line-mode` set as my default with the line `(global-visual-line-mode t)` in my `~/.emacs`. In the past, `ctrl-k` (`kill-line`) has killed the entire line in this mode, but on a recently reformatted computer, `ctrl-k` is only killing to the screen edge.

How would you suggest setting `ctrl-k` to kill past the screen edge again?

Answer (score 10):

The cause of the behavior described by the original poster is the line of code from the variable `visual-line-mode-map` within `simple.el` that states:  `(define-key map [remap kill-line] 'kill-visual-line)`

One way to reverse the process is simply removing the minor-mode key binding as follows:

```
 (define-key visual-line-mode-map [remap kill-line] nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

With emacs 28.2, this no longer seems to work.  Anyone know how to kill the entire line in more recent emacs?